# TypeError : i is not a function (AWS Lambda wrapped with epsagon)

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

This error is popped up on a lambda when I've upgraded got npm module to 11.5.x from 9.6.0.
I'm using serverlessframework to develop and deploy micro services. Using Epsagon wrapper for better monitoring.

I've been struggling with this error from the past 3 days. Any help would be well appreciated.

AWS lambda runtime: Node 10.x

following are a few npm packages
"serverless-webpack": "^5.3.3",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
"webpack": "^4.44.1"
"epsagon": "^1.82.0",
"got": "^11.6.0", (with got 9.0.6, there is no issue)

While I can't paste the entire code snippet, following is a snippet. If I use the same code in a simple index.js file and run it then I cant reproduce this issue.

```
const { body } =  await got(path, {
    headers: { 'custom-key': customKey },
    responseType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    json: { ts: i1599227703000 },
});
```

The following log snippet is from cloudWatch.

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "i is not a function",
  "stack": [
    "TypeError: i is not a function",
    "    at ClientRequest.patchedCallback (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/epsagon/dist/bundle.js:1:60626)",
    "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)",
    "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:15)",
    "    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
    "    at ClientRequest.e.emit.f [as emit] (/var/task/epsagon_handlers/abcdNameChanged-epsagon.js:2:1080726)",
    "    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:565:21)",
    "    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:17)",
    "    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:451:20)",
    "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)",
    "    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could crack it.
If we enable epsagon auto-tracing thru epsagon webapp, it actually adds a layer called epsagon-node-layer to that lambda.

Disabling auto-tracing helped to not to get this error.

For more details, refer to: https://github.com/epsagon/epsagon-node/issues/295